# xpath clarification in Salesforce application

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Create an automated test script for salesforce application using selenium webdriver with java. I have some clarification in my XPath.
Below is the HTML code for the salesforce application [Lightning mode]

```
<div one-appnavbarmenubutton_appnavbarmenubutton="" class="menuItemsWrapper" style="" xpath="1">
<slot one-appnavbarmenubutton_appnavbarmenubutton="">
<one-app-nav-bar-menu-item one-appnavbaritemdropdown_appnavbaritemdropdown="" class="slds-dropdown__item" one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem-host="">
<span one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem="" class="slds-truncate">
<span one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem="">Tech Path
</span>
</span>
</one-app-nav-bar-menu-item>
<one-app-nav-bar-menu-item one-appnavbaritemdropdown_appnavbaritemdropdown="" class="slds-dropdown__item" one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem-host="">
<span one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem="" class="slds-truncate">
<span one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem="">Keyword
</span>
</span>
</one-app-nav-bar-menu-item>
<one-app-nav-bar-menu-item one-appnavbaritemdropdown_appnavbaritemdropdown="" class="slds-dropdown__item" one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem-host="">
<span one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem="" class="slds-truncate">
<span one-appnavbarmenuitem_appnavbarmenuitem="">Invention Disclosures by Hierarchy
</span>
</span>
</one-app-nav-bar-menu-item>
</slot>
</div>
```

From the above, I want to get the total no of tag `<one-app-nav-bar-menu-item>`

below is my test script

```
WebElement menuCount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='menuItemsWrapper']//slot"))
List<WebElement>menuItemCount = menuCount.findElements(By.tagName("one-app-nav-bar-menu-item"))
```

When I executed i am getting the `menuITemCount =0`

Let me know is there any problem in my script

Environment:
chrome driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting to `By.xpath("//one-app-nav-bar-menu-item")`

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element induce WebDriverWait.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);         
WebElement menuCount=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='menuItemsWrapper']//slot")));
List<WebElement>menuItemCount = menuCount.findElements(By.xpath(".//one-app-nav-bar-menu-item"));
System.out.println(menuItemCount.size());
```